# keyboard dismiss without animation when used in UIWindow with windowLevel greater than UIWindowLevelAlert

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, keyboard, uiwindow

I am currently presenting a security code view controller that contains a UITextField in which the user is supposed to enter a passcode. This security code view controller is presented in its own window which has a "windowLevel = UIWindowLevelAlert + 1;" because i want to hide potential UIAlertView or other windows that could be present already displayed.

The problem comes when i call the resignFirstResponder method on the textfield, it seems that the keyboard is dismissed without the usual animation.
I tried to register to the various keyboard notification, and checked the UIView areAnimationsEnabled property and it returns YES.

So if anybody already had this issue, you're welcome :)

Answer (score 5):

UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey is a constant string identifier the animation duration, so there is where of enabling and disabling the animation.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                     selector:@selector(willHideKeyboard:) 
                                         name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification 
                                       object:nil];

- (void)willHideKeyboard:(NSNotification *)notification {
       [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];
  }
```

Comment: Although technically this works, it's kind of like killing a fly with a sledgehammer - it turns of all animations for everything.

Comment: You can enable animation again when keyboard hides using UIKeyboardDidHideNotification notification.